# Prompting user for input until an empty line

Tags: java

Here is my main method for a cypher program.

I'm trying to modify my code to where it prompts the user for input until an empty line is submitted

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter ");
    String message  = kb.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter encryption key: ");
    String key = kb.nextLine();
    int shift = Integer.parseInt(key);

    String encrypted = Encrpyt(message, shift);
    System.out.println("Encrypted: " + encrypted);

    String decrypted = Decrypt(message, shift);
    System.out.println("Decrypted: " + decrypted);  
}
```

Comment: Google about loops (for,while,do-while). And for the check about the string being empty there is a .isEmpty() string method. Note that a string: "    " is not a empty string only "" is a empty string. If you wish to remove leading and following whitespaces use the .trim() string method.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a while loop.

```
String line = kb.nextLine()
while (!line.equals("")) {
    (your code here)
    line = kb.nextLine();
}
```

The while loop will break when the user enters an empty line.